# Hardware that can wirelessly charge the AirPods Max?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

Is there already hardware that can wirelessly charge the AirPods Max? I already found [The Max Stand](https://www.themaxstand.com/), but the project is not finished yet.

Comment: Is there any budget/speed requirements?

Comment: Should not cost over 100 EUR and the faster the better.